# Generating DH key with specific bit-length

Tags: diffie-hellman, randomness, key-generation

In [PKCS#3](ftp://ftp.rsasecurity.com/pub/pkcs/ascii/pkcs-3.asc) the generation for DH secrets mandates to generate them with a minimum size if length is specified:

> The central authority may optionally select an integer $\ell$,
> the private-value length in bits, that satisfies $2^{\ell-1} \le p$.
> […]
>
> An integer $x$, the private value, shall be generated
> privately and randomly. This integer shall satisfy $0 < x < p-1$,
> unless the central authority specifies a private-value
> length $\ell$, in which case the integer shall satisfy
> $2^{\ell-1} \le x < 2^\ell$.

<sup>(Math formulas re-typeset in LaTeX for readability; see comments.)</sup>

The normal way to do this would be generate a random number over the whole range and loop if it does not fit (pseudo Java):

```
do {
    x = new BigInteger(lSize, random);
} while(2^(lSize-1) > x || x > 2^lSize || x > p-1); // x.bitLength!=lSize || x > p-1
```

However this results in looping at least half of the time. Would it be safe to set the most significant bit by hand and generate the rest randomly. I think yes - as the bits are supposed to be independent:

```
do {
    x = new BigInteger(lSize-1, random);
    x = x.setBit(lSize);
} while (x > p-1);
```

Is this an acceptable optimization?

Comment: Ugh, don't use lowercase `l` as identifier please. Just use `length` or `s` for size.

Comment: l is the standards name for this (the original source of JDK uses lSize (which is confsing on its own, I would prefer xSize).

Comment: Using the names from the protocol is a good thing l suppose, but l'd still prefer something like `lengthL` or similar. I've just used the mathematical symbols (Unicode) but in that case you must be sure that UTF-8 is *always* supported - so CVS is out...

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: The `l`in the original text is perfectly readable (albeit somewhat similar to a `1`), at least on my screen (obviously, it depends on which monospace font your browser uses). The problem is that, in the sans-serif font used here for plain question text, the lowercase L looks simply like a vertical bar (as does the capital I!). IMO, the solution is to either mark the quoted "monospace math" expressions as inline code (which renders them with a monospace font) or typeset them properly (preferably using a cursive $\ell$) at the cost of exact quote fidelity.

Comment: Thanks @IlmariKaronen for the typesetting. Looks great. Should be readable enough to discuss the question now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the two code snippets in your question generate the exact same distribution of random outputs $x$ (assuming that the RNG you're using is indeed indistinguishable from a true source of uniformly random bits, anyway).  Thus, it makes no difference to the outcome which of them you use.

BTW, it seems to me that *neither* of your programs correctly implements PKCS#3 section 7.1, and the difference could have potentially serious security implications.  Specifically, the problem is that your code rejects any $x$ greater than $p-1$, even though PKCS#3 does *not* impose this limit when the length $\ell$ is defined by the central authority.  As a consequence, you're not choosing $x$ randomly from the full range $2^{\ell-1} \le x < 2^\ell$, but rather from the reduced range $2^{\ell-1} \le x < \min(p, 2^\ell)$.  This could be quite disastrous for security, if e.g. $p$ happens to be only slightly greater than $2^{\ell-1}$ (which the standard allows!).

Thus, AFAICT, a correct implementation of PKCS#3 section 7.1 would look something like this:

```
if (lSize == 0) {

    // no lSize defined: choose x uniformly from 0 < x < p-1
    do {
        x = new BigInteger(p.bitLength(), random);
    } while (x == 0 || x >= p-1);

} else {

    // lSize is defined: choose x uniformly from 2^(lSize-1) <= x < 2^lSize
    x = new BigInteger(lSize-1, random);
    x = x.setBit(lSize);

}
```

Note that, in the second case, it's quite possible that $x \ge p-1$.  There is no mathematical problem with this, although obviously an implementation may wish to reduce such $x$ modulo $p-1$ before the exponentiation step for the sake of efficiency (but do beware of timing attacks possibly leaking up to a bit of the secret!).

It may also be desirable to reject $x = p-1$, as using this value would result in $y = 1$, which the other party *should* refuse to accept for obvious reasons (even though PKCS#3 does not appear to actually say so!).  Of course, in practice, the case $x = p-1$ can only happen if $2^\ell > p-1$, and then only with probability $1/2^{\ell-1}$, which should be practically negligible if $p$ is large enough to be otherwise secure.

Comment: Yes there are two different restrictions on the upper secret length and OpenJDK (where the code is from) mixes them. It is not a big problem as l has to be smaller than |p| but well....

Answer (score 3):

Sure thing. You'd lose up to one bit of security, but that's generally acceptable.

Comment: A lot of these kind of definitions come from the fact that they are made by mathematicians (most theoretical cryptographers are mathematicians rather than developers). The problem is when these things creep up into actual protocols that need to be developed. Such a loop is completely unnecessary.

Comment: The problem is that "fixing bits" in this case seems safe, but in others not. For example to limit the range of random numbers nulling bits is not safe as the resulting intgers are not evenly distributed anymore. Thats why I am careful with the setting of 1 bit, but since it is on powr-of-two boundaries it looks fine.

Comment: Actually the PKCS3 definition is better than most, it does not prescribe looping. If you followa"Applied Cryptography" book receipt (where the original code comes from) then it is more strict on requiring a loop. (For "some" good reasons as my comment above)

Comment: Yes, it depends on the algorithm. Most of the time when the bits are converted to numbers in a range it's OK (you'd just use a sub-range), but when a completely random distribution of bits is required, it's certainly not.

Comment: Wait, *how* would you lose one bit of security? The standard effectively mandates that, if a length $\ell$ is specified, the $\ell$-th bit of the secret $x$ shall equal one ($2^{\ell-1} \le x < 2^\ell$). I don't see what difference it makes to the outcome whether you *force* that bit to be 1, or just keep retrying until it is.

Comment: You lose a bit of security compared to the strength expectation of that size. Same is true for RSA primes. If you require the prime size to be exactly the bitsize half of the space is truncated. Consequently the "if l is not specified" has not this problem as it allows all values from 1 up to the modulus-1. (with risky small values).

Comment: @eckes: Ah, yes, you do lose some security when picking $x$ between $2^{\ell-1}$ and $2^\ell-1$, compared to just picking it uniformly between $1$ and $p-2$. I originally assumed that Maarten was referring to the difference between the two methods of picking $x$ between $2^{\ell-1}$ and $2^\ell-1$ shown in your question.